# How to solve for a system of equations in MATLAB when the variables are actually symbolic functions?

Tags: matlab, solver, symbolic-math

```
>> syms x v(x) w(x);
>> eq1 = 2*v + 3*w == 4;
>> eq2 = 5*v + 4*w == 3;
>> sol = solve([eq1,eq2],[v,w])
```

I tried to implement this code in MATLAB, but error flashes out as "The second argument must be a vector of symbolic variables." I have tried similar things in Python using SymPy, but never such error comes. How to correct out this?

Comment: maybe declare `v` and `w` without `(x)`?

Comment: That is not possible actually. The equation comes out after a lot of computations. I have just tried to simplify the problem using the 2 equations. The coefficients are also not numbers but symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the help file for the multivariate case of solve and the example in the help file
`openExample('symbolic/SolveMultivariateEquationsAndAssignOutputsToStructureExample')`

Applied to your problem

```
syms v w;
eq1 = [2*v + 3*w == 4;5*v + 4*w == 3];
sol = solve(eq1)
sol.v 
sol.w
```

but if you just want to solve for v w then you could use e.g.
`[2 3;5 4]\[4;3]`

Comment: Actually the variables are not independent symbols. They are dependent on a common indenpendent symbol x. The equations are just representing the actual equations which comes out after some computations. Hence I am not defining the variables. The solve() function is giving error because it cannot solve for dependent variables. I need a workaround to that.